# Как удалить символ "\" из строки?

Tags: java

Как удалить символ "\" из строки? 
Так не получается

```
 char[] array = xml.substring(64,xml.length() - 13).replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll("\'", "").toCharArray();
```

Да, можно использовать один replaceAll , но пока интересует как убрать этот символ.

Comment: \\ = обратному слешу, экранированному

Comment: @Yami , \\ = / ? 
А касательно вопроса, есть подсказка?

Comment: Думаю вам надо это `.replaceAll("\\", "")`

Comment: А вы уверены, что он там вообще есть? Он во входных данных или вы эту строку где-то подсматриваете?

Comment: @D-side, да я ее получаю и могу подсмотреть, отсюда и знаю что там есть. А мне нужно разбить весь ответ на подстроки.

Comment: @Yami, 

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^

Так понимаю что это(\\) пустое значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня сработало так.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```